# No traffic from Server A to Server B (and vise versa) but all other servers can talk to them (and vise versa)

Tags: windows, networking, sql-server-2008-r2

I can not seem to get traffic from Server A to Server B, and no traffic from Server B to Server A.  On the other hand all other servers can talk to them and they can talk to all other servers.  Just looking for suggestions on how to debug it...

**Layout:**

```
NORCL1N1 (physical)
`-NORCL2N1 (virtual)
`-NOROIT (virtual) AKA Server A

NORCL1N2 (physical)
`-NORCL2N2 (virtual) AKA Server B
```

**Server Information:**

NORCL1N1

```
Type: Microsoft Virtual Network Switch Adapter (Connected)
Mac: 18-03-73-F0-39-CA
IP: 10.71.1.4

Type: Microsoft Failover Cluster Virtual Adapter (Disconnected)
Mac: FE-5B-20-52-41-53
IP: N/A
```

NORCL2N1

```
Type: Microsoft Failover Cluster Virtual Adapter (Connected)
Mac: 02-15-5D-01-67-00
IP: 169.254.1.126

Type: Microsoft Virtual Machine Bus Network Adapter (Connected)
Mac: 00-15-5D-01-67-00
IP: 10.71.1.5, 10.71.1.12, 10.71.1.13
```

NOROIT

```
Type: Microsoft Virtual Machine Bus Network Adapter (Connected)
Mac: 00-15-5D-01-67-03
IP: 10.71.1.15
AKA: Server A
```

NORCL1N2

```
Type: HyperV Virtual NIC (Connected)
Mac: 18-03-73-F0-3A-AB
IP: 10.71.1.6, 10.71.1.8, 10.71.1.9, 10.71.1.10, 10.71.1.11

Type: Microsoft Failover Cluster Virtual Adapter (Connected)
Mac: 1A-03-73-F0-3A-A9
IP: 169.254.2.127
```

NORCL2N2

```
Type: Microsoft Failover Cluster Virtual Adapter (Disconnected)
Mac: 02-15-5D-01-6B-00
IP: 169.254.2.241

Type: Microsoft Virtual Machine Bus Network Adapter (Connected)
Mac: 00-15-5D-01-6B-00
IP: 10.71.1.7
AKA: Server B
```

Pinging everything from everything works great with the exception of pinging NORCL2N2 to NOROIT and vice versa...

I disabled all firewalls, checked all ips (tried looking into the possibility there might be another computer using the same ip), I even tried restarting the app server (NOROIT)...  Can not seem to come up with a reason why traffic between the two servers are having issues.  Any ideas?

Comment: check the mac addresses of the 2 virtual servers.

Comment: @gashach not sure what you mean.  Should I be looking for something specific?  All THREE of the virtual servers have different IPs and different MACs.  I'm not sure exactly what I should be checking for...  I updated the original post with the mac addresses...

Comment: we ran into some issues in hyper-v with servers ending up with the same mac addresses.  are the virtual servers and the hosts sharing a network adaptor?

Comment: yea they are...  I'm thinking of taking the virtuals and putting them on their own dedicated nic.  I will have my host on a teamed v-nic (three 1gb nics) and a 1gb nic dedicated to all my virtual servers on the host server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I think I figured it out...
>
> It seems like it had to do with routing.  I had to manually enter in
>   persistent routes to make sure the servers in question knew how to get
>   to each other.
>
> For example on NOROIT (open command prompt and type)...
>
> ```
> route add -p 10.71.1.7 mask 255.255.255.255 10.71.1.1 metric 1
> ```
>
> Then on NORCL2N2 type...
>
> ```
> route add -p 10.71.1.15 mask 255.255.255.255 10.71.1.1 metric 1
> ```
>
> This is a "band aid" solution and something else...  something bigger
>   is an issue...  I think it might have something to do with the Hyper-V
>   server and the virtual nics...
>
> It seems that even if I added a static route for 10.71.1.0 mask
>   255.255.255.128 it would not know how to get to the servers...  Only after adding each one was I able to get it working.

**Update / SOLUTION (this is what fixed the issue):**

It was much simpler then I was making it out to be...  It seems on the switch that I was using (Dell Layer2) the ports being used by the servers NORCL1N1 and NORCL1N2 were set up on a different VLAN.  I thought the ports were damaged on the switch at first but instead somehow there VLANs were changed when I took them out of a LAG (used for teaming).  I originally had 3 NICS on NORCL1N1 set up as a team and in turn had 3 ports on the switch set up in a LAG.  I turned towards using the NICs on the server WITHOUT teaming involved (due to issues with virtual macs, ip conflicts, etc) and wanted to dedicate a NIC for virtuals, one for cluster-heartbeat, and 1 for the host machine.  After doing that and removing the teaming from the server, then removing the LAG from the switch, I thought I was good to go...  Not so fast..  I had to go back to each port on the switch and reset the VLAN the ports belonged to again...

Seems everything is fine now!  Hope this helps someone out...